# Obtener un item de un array de objetos con javascript

Tags: javascript, json, array, local-storage, javascript-objeto

Necesito obtener un *item* de un arreglo, por ejemplo tengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito obtener solo el valor de `idusers` para almacenarlo dentro de una variable.

El array lo estoy obteniendo desde un `localStorage` con el siguiente código:

```
var registro = JSON.stringify({ sucursal:sucursal, idusers:idusers, usuario:usuario, }); //AÑADIR AL OBJETO JSON

registros.push(registro); 

storage.setItem('registros', JSON.stringify(registros));

storage = window.localStorage;
registros = storage.getItem('registros');
registros = JSON.parse(registros);

console.log(registros);
```

y en el `localstorage` los datos están almacenados como se ve en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, agrega el código asociado al problema para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: listo agrege parte del codigo

Comment: Necesitas obtener todos los idUsers que se encuentren en el array?

Comment: uno o todos de ambas maneras pueden ser utiles

Comment: creo que lo tengo, ¿puedes agregar las lineas en las que empleas `setItem()` para agregar los json al localStorage?

Comment: var registro = JSON.stringify({
      sucursal:sucursal,
      idusers:idusers,
      usuario:usuario,
   });

   //AÑADIR AL OBJETO JSON
   registros.push(registro);

   storage.setItem('registros', JSON.stringify(registros));

Comment: ahi estan la linea de codigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obtener todos los valores de un atributo en el *array* de objetos puedes recorrerlo con un `for` y agregarlo a otro *array* con `push()` de la siguiente forma:

```js
var registros =[{sucursal: 1, idusers: 1, usuario: 'schw'}
,{sucursal: 1, idusers: 2, usuario: 'schw2'}];

nregistros=[];

for(i in registros)
  nregistros.push(registros[i].idusers);

  
console.log(nregistros);
```

Para acceder a un atributo de un objeto solo debes llamarlo con un punto, (En este caso `.idusers`).

Lo anterior se aplica en un *array* de objetos normal.

---

Analizando los datos de la pregunta, tal parece que el `json` agregado al `localStorage` podría no estar bien definido:

Haciendo ingeniería inversa, para que el `JSON.parse` devuelva dicho resultado, el *json* de entrada seria el siguiente:

```js
  valores='"{"sucursal":"1","idusers":"1", "usuario": "schw"}"';
  ijson = JSON.stringify(valores);
  console.log(ijson);
```

En el anterior código se ve que el resultado no es un objeto *json* valido, por eso el método `JSON.parse()` no puede transformarlo como se espera.

Este error se produce por la forma en que se agregan los elementos al *array* de objetos `json`:

```js
var registros = [];

var registro = JSON.stringify({ sucursal:'1', idusers:'1', usuario:'schw', }); 

console.log(registro); //AÑADIR AL OBJETO JSON 

registros.push(registro); 

console.log(JSON.stringify(registros));

//no puedo ejecutar la siguiente linea por motivos de seguridad del sitio
//localStorage.setItem('registros', JSON.stringify(registros));
```

Como se aprecia en el proceso se aplica `JSON.stringify()` **2 veces** cuando solo debería aplacarse una sola vez sobre el *array* final a insertar (no es necesario aplicar `JSON.stringify()` para agregar el objeto a la variable `registro` antes de hacer `push()`).

```js
var registros = [];

var registro = { sucursal:'1', idusers:'1', usuario:'schw', }; 

console.log(registro); //AÑADIR AL OBJETO JSON 

registros.push(registro); 

console.log(JSON.stringify(registros));

//no puedo ejecutar la siguiente linea por motivos de seguridad del sitio
//localStorage.setItem('registros', JSON.stringify(registros));
```

En el código anterior se aprecia que el resultado es un *json* valido y de esa forma ya no retorna error.

De esa forma puedes resolver tu problema, saludos.

Comment: Lo intente pero no me resulto me dice undefined  :     storage = window.localStorage;
            registros = storage.getItem('registros');
            registros = JSON.parse(registros);
       
            nregistros = [];

            for(i in registros){
               nregistros.push(registros[i].idusers);
            }        
  

            console.log(nregistros);

Comment: @David intenta colocar `console.log(registros[0].idusers)` esto debería retornar 1.

Comment: lo coloce tal cual lo mencionas dentro del for pero me retorna undefined, sera porque mi arreglo tiene comillas a diferencia de tu ejemplo ?

Comment: @David las comillas no tendrían por que afectar, dame un momento para investigar, si gustas puedes agregar la información que puedas acotar a la pregunta.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda llevo mas de 1 dia intentando dar con la solucion

Comment: @David ya lo tengo resuelto, puedes echarle un vistazo.

Comment: lo revisare y te comento gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: y como accedo con el map al primer elemento del primer objeto? sin que me salten los otros 2? en el caso del map me muetra los 3, yo quiero acceder solo al primer idUser alguien me da una mano por favor.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes realizarlo utilizando el método [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map), éste te permite ir transformando tú array a uno nuevo dentro de un ciclo.

```js
let registros = [{idUser:1, userName:'user1'},{idUser:2, userName:'user2'}, {idUser:3, userName:'user3'}]

let mapIdUsers = registros.map((registro) => registro.idUser);
console.log(mapIdUsers);
```

Comment: `map` también es otra opción.

Comment: storage = window.localStorage;
            registros = storage.getItem('registros');
            registros = JSON.parse(registros);


            let mapIdUsers = registros.map((registro) => registro.idusers);
            console.log(mapIdUsers);

Comment: intente y me dice undefined

Comment: Puedes hacer un console.table(resgistros) para ver que datos tiene esa variable

Answer (score 3):

Cuando lo que queremos obtener tiene la misma longitud que el array de donde queremos extraer la información es posible usar `.map` tal como plantea la respuesta de @cjara, si además lo que queremos es una parte del objeto, en este caso una propiedad, podemos usar **destructuring**:

```js
let registros = [{idUser:1, userName:'user1'},{idUser:2, userName:'user2'}, {idUser:3, userName:'user3'}]

let mapIdUsers = registros.map(({idUser}) => idUser);

console.log(mapIdUsers);
```

`({idUser}) => idUser` quiere decir que en cada iteración solo pasamos `idUser` de todo el objeto al callback.